# Wrong runtime linker/interpreter set for 32-bit armhf when cross-compiling

Tags: gcc, linker, cross-compiling, yocto

I am utilizing yocto (dunfell) to cross-compile a project for multiple different architectures. Specifically, the targets I have are a 64-bit RaspberryPi4 (aarch64) and a 32-bit Orange Pi (armhf). My project that I am cross-compiling compiles and runs without issue when building for the raspi target; the runtime linker is properly set and things run without issue. However, whenever I build for the Orange Pi target, the program appears to compile without issue, but when I try to execute it on the platform, I get a "File not found" error.

This appears to be because the interpreter (runtime linker) is set to `/usr/lib/ld.so` which is not actually on the system. See below:

```
$ file my-exec
my-exec: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /usr/lib/ld.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped
```

In contrast, when I build the same program for the raspi target, the interpreter seems to be set properly for the system:

```
$ file my-exec
my-exec: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped
```

This issue seems to be isolated to just this project on the Orange Pi target. In comparison, other projects on the Orange Pi target look like the following and run without issue:

```
$ file other-exec
other-exec: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

What I am trying to understand is the following:

1. Which things could possibly be influencing the interpreter which is chosen at compile time? I have done some digging into this and nothing is explicitly set in my Makefile which could be causing this. Additionally, when I build a simple hello world application, the correct interpreter is chosen. It seems to be some set of flags in my compiling/linking which is causing this. Below is the compiling/linking output (I have excluded all the libraries it is also building which use the same arguments):

```
NOTE: make -j 24 i2c-core VERBOSE=1 CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7ve -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/my-yocto-os/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-exec/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot LD=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld --sysroot=/home/my-yocto-os/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-exec/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot 

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7ve -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/my-yocto-os/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-exec/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot -I.. -I. -g -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wno-long-long -Wconversion -Wstrict-prototypes -DBUILD_CORE -c -o build/other.o ../other.c


...


arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld --sysroot=/home/my-yocto-os/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-exec/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot  build/my-exec.o build/other.o build/other1.o -luv -lsystemd -lc --entry main -o build/exe/my-exec
```

2. The linker which is being set (`/usr/lib/ld.so.1`) seems to be a really common linker to use, so why doesn't it actually end up on my system?
3. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about the ARM architecture which is resulting in this outcome? Are there different flags I could set at linking which would resolve this?

One further piece of information I have, which may or may not be relevant is the following:
An issue I hit while building for the Raspi target (showed up on both targets, actually) was the compiler wasn't able to find the entry symbol. This is quite a mature project and cross-compilers have been used to compile it, historically, but in a way that isn't yocto. This has never been an issue in the past. It wasn't until I added `--entry main` to the linker flags that this issue was resolved. I am wondering if there is a more fundamental problem which is resulting in these odd outcomes.

Thank you for any help you can provide on this. Please let me know if you have any additional questions about my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of debugging, I figured out there problem. If anyone with more knowledge than I on linking would like to chime in to add things, please do. Ultimately, this was resolved by using `gcc` as the linker as opposed to using `ld` (the ones provided by yocto's cross compiler; i.e. `aarch64-poky-linux-gcc`).

In order to do this, I modified my recipe to pass in `LD=${CC} LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS}` to my Makefile. Now, it builds and executes properly for both the RPi and OrangePi targets.

I believe this is mainly the case because the `LDFLAGS` provided by yocto actually can't be parsed by `ld`. From my research, it looks like `ld` is typically invoked by `gcc`. However, the flags still need to get to the complier. So, originally, `LDFLAGS` that needed to be passed into linking, weren't being passed in at all because I just assumed there was an error with doing it that way. So, be sure you're passing your `LDFLAGS` that yocto gives you into `gcc`.